# "Python has stopped Working" on reaching the line "model.add(LSTM..." in the function below

Tags: python

```
def _build_network(self, vocab_size, maxlen, embedding_dimension=256, hidden_units=256, trainable=False):
    print('Build model...')
    model = Sequential()
    print('Reached here')

    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dimension, input_length=maxlen, embeddings_initializer='glorot_normal'))
    print('embedding done')

    model.add(Convolution1D(hidden_units, 3, kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='valid', activation='sigmoid',
                            input_shape=(1, maxlen)))
    # model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
    model.add(Convolution1D(hidden_units, 3, kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='valid', activation='sigmoid',
                            input_shape=(1, maxlen - 2)))
    print('conv1dcomplete')
    # model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))

    # model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='sigmoid', dropout=0.5, return_sequences=True))
    #print('Reached here')

    model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='sigmoid', dropout=0.5))

    model.add(Dense(hidden_units, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    print('No of parameter:', model.count_params())
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

Using Anaconda-spyder Python 3.6 with latest versions of tensorflow and keras. Running on Windows 7 64-bit. Before the line where LSTM is being called, everything gets printed but then, suddenly on reaching this line Python crashes.

Comment: It will be helpful if you have a more detailed error output to include it in your question. This will help people understand the problem better.